# Spawning enemies outside of view

Tags: 2d, android, shooter

I'm trying to create a 2d shooter for Android. How do I spawn enemies "above" the screen, so that they "enter" the game screen instead of spawning at the top of it?

I think I need to make a game screen that is bigger than the actual view. How would I do this?
I know that negative y-values would work, however that's not really the same.

EDIT: I'm using canvas and bitmaps.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity and removed the other questions in the process. You can still ask them as separate questions - it's just easier for people to find information if each question is really one question.

Comment: Why aren't you using negative y values if they would work?

Comment: Don't overanalyze it! It's perfectly fine to use negative x y values.

Comment: What they said, in addition, your enemies won't need background and stuff while off screen, if that is what you worry about, they just don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could spawn the enemies with negative y-coordinates.  However, if for some reason you can't do that, you can instead have a "game screen" that is bigger than the size of the view screen.  Just render the center part of this game screen, and spawn enemies on the non-rendered outer edges of the game screen.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why the OP can't use negative x and y values - they've always worked fine for me!